# Mahout (0.8) CVB VectorDump

Tags: mahout

I am trying to run the CVB on a directory of plain text files, following the procedure outlined below. However, I am not able to see the vectordump (step 6). Run without the "-c csv" flag the generated file is empty. However, if I use the flag "-c csv" the generated file starts with a series of numbers followed by an alphabetically organized series of unigrams (see below)

```
#1,10,1163,12,121,13,14,141,1462,15,16,17,185,1901,197,2,201,2227,23,283,298,3,331,35,4,402,4351,445,5,57,58,6,68,7,9,987,a.m,ab,abc,abercrombie,abercrombies,ability
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

thank you

0: Set Paths

```
> export HDFS_PATH=/path/to/hdfs/
> export LOCAL_PATH=/path/to/localfs
```

1: Put docs in HDFS using hadoop fs -put [-put  ... ]

```
> hadoop fs -put $LOCAL_PATH/test $HDFS_PATH/rawdata
```

2: Generate sequence files (of Text) from a directory

```
> mahout seqdirectory \
-i $HDFS_PATH/rawdata \    
-o $HDFS_PATH/sequenced \    
-c UTF-8 -chunk 5
```

3- Generate sparse Vector from Text sequence files

```
> mahout seq2sparse \
-i $HDFS_PATH/sequenced \
-o $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors \
-ow --maxDFPercent 85 --namedVector --weight tf
```

4- rowid: : Map SequenceFile to {SequenceFile, SequenceFile}

```
> mahout rowid \
-i $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors/tfidf-vectors \
-o $HDFS_PATH/matrix
```

5- run cvb

```
> mahout cvb \
-i $HDFS_PATH/matrix/matrix \
-o $HDFS_PATH/test-lda \
-k 100 -ow -x 40 \
-dict $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-0 \
-dt $HDFS_PATH/test-lda-topics \
-mt $HDFS_PATH/test-lda-model
```

6- Dump vectors from a sequence file to text

```
> mahout vectordump \
-i $HDFS_PATH/test-lda-topics/part-m-00000 \
-o $LOCAL_PATH/vectordump \
-vs 10 -p true \
-d $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-0 \
-dt sequencefile \
-sort $HDFS_PATH/test-lda-topics/part-m-00000 \
-c csv 
;  cat $LOCAL_PATH/vectordump
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in step 4. In step 3 I am generating TF vectors (--weight tf) but in step 4 I was running the rowid job (which converts the `<Text, VectorWritable>` tuples of tf-vectors, to `<IntWritable, VectorWritable>` which cvb expects) with tfidf-vectors.

So changing step 4 from:

```
> mahout rowid \
-i $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors/tfidf-vectors \
-o $HDFS_PATH/matrix
```

to

```
> mahout rowid \
-i $HDFS_PATH/sparseVectors/tf-vectors\
-o $HDFS_PATH/matrix
```

fixes the problem.